# What is the difference between a BehaviorSubject and a ReactiveProperty in UniRx?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reactive-programming, unirx

What is the difference? To me they seem very similar... Why would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're similar in that they will both store the last given value & you can access them via the public property.

Difference is:

- `ReactiveProperty` will issue an event **if and only if the value has changed**.
- `BehaviorSubject` will issue an event whatever the new value may be.

In their C# code (which is open-sourced) `ReacitveProperty` checks equality of new value and last value; `BehaviorSubject` doesn't. In fact none of `ISubject` implementations checks the equality.

When should you use one over another?

I would use `ReactiveProperty` when I want callbacks only times the value has changed even though the substitution may occur more frequently. I would use `BehaviourSubject` when I want callbacks whenever the substitution occurred.

In most cases `ReactiveProperty` is more useful because generally you want to react to changes. `BehaviorSubject` has its own use although less common.

Other considerations:

- `ReactiveProperty.SetValueAndForceNotify()` can be used to invoke callbacks regardless the equality.
- `IObservable.DistinctUntilChanged()` can be used to (secondarily) introduce the equality check.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the differences mentioned in other answers is `BehaviorSubject` is kinda more encapsulated compared to `ReactiveProperty`. That is:

- `BehaviorSubject.Value` is `get` only (but `.OnNext(value)` is still publicly available).
- `ReactiveProperty.Value` is settable publicly.

Answer (score -1):

Behaviour Subject is one of the implementations of the Subject class. It allows you to retrieve the last value that was pushed by using the *outObserver*.

Reactive Property is used to provide some sort notification when something happened, it's a simpler alternative to callbacks.

For example:
If you want to chain a lot of methods to an action in your game for instance the movement of an player you can use this **Rective Property**.

If you want to get the last value that was pushed for instance to make a combo in a fighting game you can use **Behaviour Subject**.

Comment: I thought the `ReactiveProperty` also stored the last value?